# Out of memory ERROR when using Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I'm using Fragment for my first time I put 3 Fragments in my activity ,
the problem is when I open the activity for the first time (only for the first time) I get this error :

```
04-28 17:51:02.539 5001-5001/com.example.dell.jsonapplication E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 22125220-byte allocation.
        04-28 17:51:04.659 2427-2427/? E/Thermal-daemon: [flash_led] temp_new :30  temp_old :31
```

although my app is very small ! 
and here is the activity which contains the fragments :

```
package com.example.dell.jsonapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class GuidActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guid);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_guid, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Guid1();
            case 1:
                return new Guid2();
            case 2:
                return new Guid3();
            default :
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

and here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".GuidActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_frag"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="left|center" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/next_frag"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|center" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/frag_progress"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
```

Please help :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Guid1();
            case 1:
                return new Guid2();
            case 2:
                return new Guid3();
            default :
                return null;

        }
    }
```

Why don't you:

```
List<Fragment> myFragments = new ArrayList();

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    myFragments.add(new Guid1());
    myFragments.add(new Guid2());
    myFragments.add(new Guid3());
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position < myFragments.size()) {
        return myFragments.get(position);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

After studying your code, my guess is that you are filling the heap with fragment instances. With this approach, you guarantee that you only create the fragments when the Adapter is created, on the application's start. We simply store them in memory while the app is running, instead of creating a new one each time you want to present a fragment.

Let me know if this helped.

---

UPDATE:

I usually create my Fragments oustide the Adapter with the help of addFragment().

Like so:

```
// here we set up our own adapter...
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// ...add the fragments we want...
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Guid1());
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Guid2());
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Guid3());

// ...and set up our own adapter on the viewpager
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

And here is a formula I use to create my own adapters:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**Adds a fragment and corresponding title to the list*/
    public void addFragment(Fragment f, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(f);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same Error :(
I found this commented note at the beginning of class GuidActivity :

Comment: /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */

Comment: Yep. Absolutely. If it does work, please post your solution and mark it as correct for future viewers ;)

Comment: well , actually I don't know how to do it , can you explain please what should be changed in my code ( I'm new in fragments :o )

Comment: #Luís Henriques  need your help please.

Comment: Sorry. I'm back :D Simply, instead of using a SectionsPagerAdapter, use a FragmentPagerAdapter. I'll update my post with new code.

Comment: Now that I took a closer look at your code, I verified that you are already using a FragmentPagerAdapter. Your custom SectionsPagerAdapter already extends it. You are doing everything correctly in that regard. But why are you using the SupportFrafgmentManager and not simply the FragmentManager? Try replacing "getSupportFragmentManager()" with "getFragmentManager()". Other than that, I got nothing for you, mate. Sorry... :(

Comment: I went and took a look at my fragment notes. I usually create the fragments outside the adapter. not inside it. I edited my post to show you how I do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: same think Luis :'(

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different codes and finally I tried this :

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in Manifasets, It works for me.

Comment: Yeah. Glad to hear it. But of course it works. You are allocating a large chunck of memory to your application. The thing is, with such a simple application, you shouldn't require a large heap. Something is still wrong with your app. But if you're ok with it, it's fine. Mark it as the correct answer if you think it is appropraite.